# When does CRFClassifier start showing results different from text matching?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm very new to NLP and just learned about CRFClassifiers for Named Entity Recognition. I followed this tutorial to train my classifier https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html

At this point, it "looks" no different than if I had a giant set of named entities and for each word in the test file, I could check if it exists in the giant set.

I'm trying to develop an intuition about when and how the results of this classifier will start to look different than that. Under what circumstances and in what way are CRFClassifiers better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 examples off of the top of my head:

1. Ambiguous term:

`The actor Jeremy London was cast in the show.`

2. Terms not in your dictionary:

`She has worked for Xytrocorp for the last 3 years.`

`They had a meeting with Joe Rarelastname last week.`

I would say especially the second is a major reason you'd want a CRFClassifier.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work for only work for foo where foo is a certain property. For example, only work for "I like {color}" but not match "I like {place}" or "I like {random}".